# Working with TF Retrained Model

Tags: python, go, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand how to properly use a re-trained model that was generated using [TensorFlow Retrain](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py)
In [Golang classifier](https://outcrawl.com/image-recognition-api-go-tensorflow/).

I'm getting different results when I use the different models (extremely different and **wrong results** when using the Golang classifier)

After iterating the graph's operations I made some modifications to the Go app for it to work:

```
session.Run(
map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
    graph.Operation("Mul").Output(0): tensor, // was "input"
},
[]tf.Output{
    graph.Operation("final_result").Output(0), // was "output"
},
nil)
```

and

```
const (
    H, W= 299, 299 // was 224,224
    Mean= float32(128) // was 117
    Scale= float32(1)
)
```

Am I loading the graph properly? is it wrong for the Mul operation to be first?
perhaps the resizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue. I've modified the sizes to correspond to the newly trained model. however the scaling remained as 1 instead of 128.
now the results are reasonably well.